# Create a singleton class to access ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

I have a class, in my WCF service, which uses ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity for getting the client identity. This all works well. I would like to have the class as a singleton so I can access it anywhere without creating new instances repeatedly. The `InstanceContextMode` I am using is `PerSession` and `ConcurrencyMode` is `Single`.

How can I do this and should I be concerned about any gotchas? By the way the class uses impersonation and loads information from the database for the domain login and caches it for the duration of WCF operation.

Answer (score 0):

WCF will automatically create a singleton with the following:

```
InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single
```

> **Single**: A single InstanceContext (and therefore service object)
>   handles all client requests for the lifetime of the application.

```
ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple
```

ConcurrencyMode.Multiple will support more than one concurrent user.

More on this stuff here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193(v=vs.110).aspx

From my experience, implementing singletons should be avoided as there can be performance problems, especially if they aren't multi-threaded. Even if you are using ConcurrencyMode.Multiple - there is no guarantee of thread synchronization (you must handle this yourself).

More on [Synchronizing Data for Multithreading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8chs7ft(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: My question was not about InstanceContextMode or ConcurrencyMode. I fully understand those. Why would this cause performance problems and why especially if not multi-threaded? I don't agree with you unless you enlighten me.

Comment: The setting values in your post do not support a WCF singleton. Hence my answer around having the correct setting values as well as the potential gotcha with thread synchronization.